# How to set color for drawable background in android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, view

I want to create a view like this in android studio  https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTm5P.png

As you can see, three views are using the same background but with different colors. I wonder how to create a view like this with only one drawable background file. Three views are using the same drawable background file, and I can set a different color for each view.

Comment: The easiest way is not to use 1 file, but to use 3.  Beyond that, the next easiest is to make a custom Drawable class in code that takes the color as a parameter and tints the drawable.

Comment: I don't want to use 3 files because I think when I want to change my background, I need to change three files, so it is a waste of time. Can you give me some instructions about how to make a custom drawable class which can take the color as a parameter, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `android:backgroundTint` for this purpose.

For example:

1. Define rounded drawable (ex: `rounded.xml`)

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>    android:shape="rectangle">
>     <corners android:radius="10dp" />
> </shape>
> ```

2. Set your color with `backgroundTint`

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
>     android:background="@drawable/rounded"/>
> ```